# Compare two SQL tables and return count of rows with changes

Tags: python, sql, hive, hiveql

I have two partitions from an SQL table containing num_key records. I need to compare and count changes in the February records versus the January records.

SAMPLE DATA AND DESIRED RESULTS:

ptn_dt = '2019-01-31' (January)

| num_key | active_indicator |
| --- | --- |
| 111 | true |
| 112 | false |
| 113 | false |
| 114 | false |
| 115 | true |
| 116 | true |

ptn_dt = '2019-02-28' (February)

| num_key | active_indicator |
| --- | --- |
| 111 | true |
| 112 | false |
| 113 | true |
| 114 | true |
| 115 | true |
| 116 | true |
| 117 | true |
| 118 | false |
| 119 | true |

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

Count of NEW entries (num_key in Feb but not in Jan) with active_indicator = 'true' ---> 2 (pertains to num_key 117 and 119)

Count of entries WITH CHANGE in active_indicator (false to true) between Jan and Feb ---> 2 (pertains to num_key 113 and 114

Count of entries WITH NO CHANGE in active_indicator (true to true) between Jan and Feb ---> 3 (pertains to num_key 111, 115 and 116

What SQL query could I use? I need to get the count of all active_indicator=true in the February partition but divided into 3 outputs (new entries, false to true from Jan to Feb, and true to true from Jan to Feb).

Comment: maybe first you should `JOIN` them by `num_key` (but I don't remeber if it sould be `INNER JOIN`, `OUTER JOIN`, or other) and for every `num_key` you will have both values (FEB, JAN) in one row. So you can compare them to get with changes, and without changes. If you get `None` in `JAN` then you will know it is new value in `FEB`.

Comment: @JMDR . . . I answered this question already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use full join (Full join returns joined records, plus not joined from left table, plus not joined from right table). Use case expressions with count():

```
select
       count(case when t1.num_key is null then 1 else null end) as cnt_new,
       count(case when t1.active_indicator = false and t2.active_indicator = true then 1 else null end) as cnt_false_to_true,
       count(case when t1.active_indicator = true and  t2.active_indicator = true then 1 else null end) as cnt_true_not_changed
 from (select * from table t1 where t1.ptn_dt = '2019-01-31') t1
      full join (select * from table t2 where ptn_dt = '2019-02-28' ) t2
           on t1.num_key = t2.num_key
```